# Does Go scheduler also manages non-Go Thread created in runtime?

Tags: winapi, go

As far as I know, Go runtime scheduler manages some number of OS Threads(probably more than GOMAXPROCS?) and Go routines by assigning Go routines to OS Threads continuously.

So this basically means that the execution of Go routines, including main goroutine , are managed by both of go scheduler and OS' thread scheudling.

Now here's my questions..

1. Does the execution of goroutine fully managed by OS' thread scheduling if I call `runtime.LockOSThread()` at the start of that goroutine?
2. Does the execution of non-Go thread also fully managed by OS' thread scheduling? In other words, if I create a non-Go Thread by `CreateThread` function (Windows), then the management non-Go Thread's execution is out of scope of Go's runtime scheduler?
3. What if I launch another goroutine with `go func()` in that non-Go Thread? How that non-Go Thread and goroutine's execution is managed?
4. Currently, I'm writing a program in Golang which runs a windows message loop in `main()` function of go program.
   Most of the time it worked well, but sometimes the message loop get blocked and resumed after few seconds and then large amount of old messages get pumped.
   (My another question: [Windows Message Loop is getting blocked and resumed intermittently (golang)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220552/windows-message-loop-is-getting-blocked-and-resumed-intermittently-golang))

   I had no idea why it occurs, so I suspected main goroutine's OS Thread switch by go scheduler. So I added `runtime.LockOSThread()` at the start of `main()` function to ensure windows message loop always run in the same thread.
   However, the problem still occured!

   I still have no idea why it occurs, but I'm suspecting this is because of Go scheduler because the same logic written in Python 3.4 didn't make any problems like this.

   So what I'm trying now is creating a new Windows Thread (non-Go Thread) by calling `CreateThread(...)` function, and running windows message loop in that thread.

   But I'm curious that whether this approach is different with calling `runtime.LockOSThread()` in main goroutine running windows message loop from Go runtime scheduler's perspective.

   So my question is, 'If I create a new non-Go Thread with `CreateThread(...)` function and run windows message loop in that thread, then does execution of that thread not affected by Go's runtime scheduler?'

Any helps or ideas will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't safely use a new OS thread without support form the runtime, either by letting the runtime spawn the thread or using cgo. You can't pin a goroutine to a thread any better than with LockOSThread. I think you need to find out what your app is doing while it's blocked.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for your comment. I'm having a hard time figuring out what my app is doing while it's blocked.. because this problem occurs at the random time.
Could you give me any suggestion or tools to figuring out  what my program is doing while it's blocked? Thanks

Comment: Check the package `runtime` docs and see if you can use one of the `GODEBUG` environment variable settings to see if the pauses you're getting correspond to GC pauses or not. You can alternatively try this: use `CreateThread()` from some C code to create a thread Go doesn't know about and both create your window AND pump messages there. Memory management will be a bit tougher here, but `SendMessageW()` can be used to send messages across threads, so basic communication from Go to C will work. (I was going to do this with my package ui before starting the libui rewrite. I might still do this.)

Comment: Instead of continuing working on your previous question and replying that `runtime.LockOSThread()` didn't help you, you post a new question with general and unclear questions and then go on discussing the issue of your previous question? That's what the previous post is for! As for your question for tools to use: (1) Attach a debugger once you're blocked; (2) Generate a dump once you're blocked; (3) Use Process Explorer / Process Hacker to see what the threads are doing when you're blocked; (4) Run your program under a profiler; (5) ...

Answer (score 1):

If you run a new OS thread using the `CreateThread()` routine, Go's scheduler will not touch the thread. However, you will then have to implement a way for that thread to communicate with Goroutines. You can't, for instance, call a Go method directly from the thread created by `CreateThread()`. Instead, you will have to use some C-based system to poll events from a Goroutine.

As an aside, if you want to run the loop from the main OS thread, you should call `LockOSThread()` in `init()` rather than in `main()`. See https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/LockOSThread:

```
func init() {
    runtime.LockOSThread();
}
func main() {
    // Run loop here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What's the difference of calling `LockOSThread()` in `init()` function and `main()` function? Isn't calling goroutine get locked to os thread if I call `LockOSThread()` at the beginning of `main()` function?

Comment: Using LockOSThread() in init ensures that main() is run from the main OS thread. Oftentimes, OS-specific APIs like runloops only work properly if they are called from the main thread. I do not know if that's the case for the windows runloop--it may not be.

Comment: Really late, but for the benefit of Googlers: until it's explicitly documented as doing so, `runtime.LockOSThread()` doesn't guarantee anything even if running in `init()`. Of course, Windows doesn't care *which* thread you do your thread-specific stuff, so long as you choose one. (OS X is an example of an OS that demands runloops be on the first thread the OS creates.)